# I need help with some SD card troubles

Tags: sd-card

I have a Samsung core 2 I have android kernel version think is 4.4. I recently ran out of memory and installed a 8gb SD card but my apps won't store there. When I try to install an app it says insufficient memory. Help please

Comment: I down-voted this because it has been asked hundreds of times before. Please Google search for answers before posting a question like this and try to solve it for yourself. Please also describe what you have done to try and fix the problem. But to be clear, the SD card has nothing to do with installing apps. Apps are installed on the internal memory. **The best thing to do is to go to your System Settings-> Storage and find what exactly is taking up space.** If your system storage is full (or close) it can cause more problems than just installing apps.

Comment: There are several apps that visualize what's taking up memory. You can get a better insight with [Storage Analayser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rjhartsoftware.storageanalyzer),[DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo),[Disk Usage & Storage Analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive), [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) or [Memory map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jzap.memorymap)

Answer (score 0):

You must move applications one by one from internal memory to SD card.
For help in this download this application: "AppMgr III (App 2 SD)".

Answer (score 0):

1. Root your device by using any rooting method ( I used kingo root).
2. Download (link2sd).
3. Use your computer to make partitions on your SD card (two partitions) ... make the first one fat32 and leave the second one without a type.
4. Insert your SD and go to link2sd it'll ask you about the type of the second partition, choose ext2.
5. Choose the app you want to move to your SD and choose great link.
   This method worked for me your apps will be stored in the ext2 partition and it will be used as extra internal memory and the fat32 partition stays as your external SD if you made each of your partitions 4 GB you get 4GB extra internal memory and 4Gb external.

Comment: Seriously- rooting is not the answer to every question. This is an extensive suggestion considering we don't really know what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @paulmz this is the method that worked for me, I'm just trying to help